# Styling columns in form

Tags: css

I have the following form.  How do I create this look without `<table>`.  Thanks

```
<table>
<tr><td><label for="firstname">First Name</label></td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="lastname">Last Name</label></td><td><input type="text" name="lastname" id="firstname" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="phone">Phone</label></td><td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="email">Email</label></td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="address">address</label></td><td><input type="text" name="address" id="address" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="city">City</label></td><td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="State">state</label></td><td><input type="text" name="state" id="state" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @John - Got rid of the <table> tags and added .label {width:30px;}

Comment: I didn't test this, but if you put <div class="table-view"> instead of <table>, <div class="table-row-view"> instead of <tr> and <div class="table-cell-view"> instead of td, where the css definition of table-view, table-row-view and table-cell-view would be display: table; display: table-row; and display: table-cell; respectively, I believe it should display equivalently as your current setup. Let me know if this works, I will put an answer containing this idea then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This enough for basic styling:

```
input {
    display: block;
}
label {
    width: 100px; /* whatever value you wish */
    float: left;
}
```

You can see how this works at http://dabblet.com/gist/2794359

---

`.label {width:30px;}` certainly won't do it. First of all, because when you write `.label`, that selects elements having a class called label. Secondly, even if you didn't use the dot, the `label` element is by default an inline element, so setting a width on it is useless if you don't give it a `display: block` as well (floating it also does the trick).

Comment: Thanks Ana,  Looks and works great except when a given table gets a little longer.  Try changing to <label for="phone">Phone and something else</label>

Comment: You can increase the width of the label. I set it to 100px, but you can make it wider. Also, you can put every label and input pair in a div as that works better for labels that have more than one row.

Comment: Thanks Ana.  You said 100px but I saw 100%.  I just noticed it and fixed it and it works great!

Comment: Also, thank you about your remarks about inline.  I did mean label and not .label, but the display:block and float part helped.

Comment: No, it is not enough, or adequate. It means making a wild guess on the width of the labels, instead of letting normal table formatting take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this styles:

**CSS** markup:

```
.divContainer 
{
    display: table;
}

.divRow  
 {
    display: table-row;
}

.divColumn 
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**HTML** markup:

```
<div class="divContainer">
    <div class="divRow">
        <div class="divColumn">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="divColumn">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="firstname"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<div/>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
}

.row > div:first-child {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.row > div:last-child {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4g2u/1/
    ​

Answer (score 0):

Apart from religious-like issues, there is no reason to format tabular data such as a form without using table markup. But if you must, the technique described in the answer of Luis Sánchez comes closest – but it is just simulating tables in CSS, with more limited browser support.